# NestList using Sum of already generated numbers

Tags: recursion

I need to do list of numbers, which are generated by recursion like

```
a_t = Sum[a_i, {i,0,t-1}]*b
```

I can do it using [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) and [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) functions, but is there any possibility to perform it by [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html), [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html) functions.

There is a code with Module and Table, where x0=66,n0=100,shock=0.8 and qstar is a list of mortality rates.

```
detDxt[x0_, n0_, shock_, qstar_, t_] := 
 Module[{DD = Table[Unique[], {t}], i, j},
  DD[[1]] = Round[shock*n0*qstar[[x0]]];
  Table[DD[[i + 1]] = 
    Round[shock*(n0 - Sum[DD[[j]], {j, 1, i}])*qstar[[x0 + i]]], {i, 
    1, t - 2}]; 
  DD[[t]] = 
   Round[(n0 - Sum[DD[[j]], {j, 1, t - 1}])*qstar[[x0 + t - 1]]];
  DD]
```

Comment: Have you seen `RecurrenceTable[]`?

Comment: The code you show can't have worked for you, since it uses the underscore character in a way that is not admissible in *Mathematica* (the underscore has special meaning in pattern matching). Why don't you show us the code you actually have (the Module, Table stuff), and we'll go from there?

Comment: I have heard about it, but never used it.

Comment: Now would be a good time to read about it in the docs, then.

Comment: FWIW your `Table` is just a `Do` loop since you don't assign the result to anything.  For readability you should actually use `Do` for such things.

Answer (score 2):

You should really look into `RecurrenceTable`, but here's the closest I've got with the functions you've asked for your example function:

```
a[t_] := Last @ Nest[Append[#, (#*b)& @* Total @ #] &, {a[0]}, t] /; t > 0

a[1] == b a[0] 
a[2] == b (a[0] + b a[0])
...
```

I don't see how `NestList`, `FoldList` and friends can help, since they don't provide the "history" list to the nesting/folding function.

Answer (score 2):

Using [RSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html)

```
Clear[a]

a[t_] = a[t] /. 
  RSolve[{a[t] == Sum[a[i], {i, 0, t - 1}]*b, a[0] == a0}, a[t], t][[1]]
```

[image]

```
tab1 = Table[a[t], {t, 0, 10}]

(*  {a0, a0 b, a0 b (1 + b), a0 b (1 + b)^2, a0 b (1 + b)^3, a0 b (1 + b)^4, 
 a0 b (1 + b)^5, a0 b (1 + b)^6, a0 b (1 + b)^7, a0 b (1 + b)^8, 
 a0 b (1 + b)^9}  *)
```

Comparing with straight recurrence

```
Clear[a]

a[0] = a0;
a[t_] := a[t] = Sum[a[i], {i, 0, t - 1}]*b;

(Table[a[t], {t, 0, 10}] // Simplify) === tab1

(*  True  *)
```

EDIT: Since your actual equations make use of `Round` they are non-linear. Use memorization with the recurrence.

```
detDxt[x0_, n0_, shock_, qstar_, t_] :=
 Module[
  {DD}, DD[1] = Round[shock*n0*qstar[[x0]]];
  DD[i_] := DD[i] =
    Round[shock*(n0 - Sum[DD[j], {j, 1, i - 1}])*qstar[[x0 + i - 1]]];
  DD[t] = Round[(n0 - Sum[DD[j], {j, 1, t - 1}])*qstar[[x0 + t - 1]]];
  DD /@ Range[t]]
```

Since you did not provide `qstar` I have generated random values on (0, 1)

```
qstar = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 200];

detDxt[66, 100, 0.8, qstar, 20]

(*  {9, 5, 62, 6, 13, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}  *)
```

Comment: This is what i have already done, chcek my code in question, but i do not want to use table function.

Comment: I have tried it for my data, but i can see, that the last DD[t] is performed by DD[i_] := DD[i] =
    Round[shock*(n0 - Sum[DD[j], {j, 1, i - 1}])*qstar[[x0 + i - 1]]], but i need the last DD[t] to be calculated by DD[t] = Round[(n0 - Sum[DD[j], {j, 1, t - 1}])*qstar[[x0 + t - 1]]]. Is there any chance to do it?

Comment: There is no shock variable in the last value i mean in DD[t] ... so it is different

Comment: Sorry, you are right, it is the same. I used for `t` variable `41.` and it shows me different lists of numbers, but when i used `41` it was alright.